# App builded successfully and listened but deploy failed in the end on Render

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, render

this is my first time hosting a REST API on Render. Everything is successful with deployment and my app is listening but at the end deploy fails (since now for several times at least). What do I do? Address is also set on `0.0.0.0`.

Here are some logs:

```
May 9 01:07:49 AM ==> Build successful  
May 9 01:07:49 AM ==> Deploying... 
May 9 02:35:06 AM ==> Starting service with 'npm run serve' 
May 9 02:35:11 AM > backend@1.0.0 serve 
May 9 02:35:11 AM > nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js [nodemon] 2.0.19 
May 9 02:35:12 AM [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
May 9 02:35:12 AM [nodemon] watching path(s): *.* 
May 9 02:35:12 AM [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json 
May 9 02:35:12 AM [nodemon] startingbabel-node src/index.js 
May 9 02:35:41 AM Listening on port 5000! 
May 9 02:35:42 AM Sucess
```